# Hide text after user login?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need to hide a block of text once the user has log in. The web page is in Wordpress with Avada, Fusion Builder. I've found this code that could help me 
but I don't know where to put it. Thanks.

```
<?php 
 function hide_asso() {
"Some kind of display:none"
}
 add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');
?>
```

So I found a function where I can put the code but there is an error somewhere:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $user_login = ( isset( $_GET['log'] ) ) ?  $_GET['log'] : '';
                $div1 .='<div id="general"'. '</div>' { echo 'display:none';};
```

Comment: Wordpress adds a body-class of `logged-in` when a user is logged in. If you wrap the text in question in an element with a class you can use as a selector to target, you will be able to hide it, e.g: `.logged-in .text-to-hide-when-logged-in { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try to find where the text is, in the template. Then add this to that template.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    <p>Text here...</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @Ivan Yes why wouldn't? `is_user_logged_in()` returns an boolean?

Comment: I am not concerned with `is_user_logged_in()` but more by your if else statement as it is out of the PHP tags, is it not going to print it anyway?
I've replaced `is_user_logged_in()` by `true` on http://www.writephponline.com/ and your code doesn't show the the HTML text

Comment: @Ivan This is a shorthand if statement, don't not understand what you are mean?

Comment: I know I know, but just try it on http://www.writephponline.com/ with an always true condition and you'll see it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ivan Maybe online just tested in actual WP environment with debug set to true and I get no warnings or errors..

Comment: Ok, no problem then